# Accessing files outside of compiled jar/war file

Tags: java, spring-boot

I build a Spring Boot application that fetch some data from a website api, and saves the response as a .json file (to cache the data and not pull new content on every page refresh)

I have then packed the application in a .jar file. But when trying to run it. I get *java.io.FileNotFoundException* everytime I try to load the file. Researched a bit and I need to fetch the .json file as a stream. But I also want to override the file, when the cache is older than 5 minutes. Have also tried to use the maven-resources-plugin to relocate the the json files in a folder "JSON" on the root of the "target" folder.

So my question is: how do I access the file from the JSON folder in the root folder where my .jar file is located? I have tried using "./JSON/file.json" and ".JSON/file.json" but both throws FileNotFoundException exception.

EDIT: [added file structure of compiled project.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zobCT.png)

Comment: Could you show us the folder structure you have ? (where is the JAR, where is the JSON, etc ..)

Comment: Try copying your compiled .jar and JSON folder to another directory and run it on the console with `java -jar your_jar_name.jar` to see if it works.

Comment: @Paschoal I have already tried that. I'm running the .jar file on my mac using the terminal command: `java -jar tracker-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`

Comment: @Bryde please avoid posting images of text, as some users (including myself) might not be able to view them. Prefer plain text for this.

Answer (score 2):

You should always specify the absolute path of external resources (outside the classpath). This is necessary because if you specify a relative path, application will search starting from the classpath and not from the folder which include the jar and the json folder.

You can do something like this:

```
new FileInputStream(new File("file://absolute_path/json/jsonfile.json"));
```

Comment: What are a good way for getting the absolute_path for the .jar file? As I will later on be moving the project to a server. And then the path will have changed.

Comment: You should externalize the configuration. With spring you can use the external conf file ( [look here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.5.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) ). In this way for each installation you can edit the absolute path.

Comment: my external file is not a configuration file for the project itself. But even trying to input the absolute path to the file don't work. I print out the path before trying to read the content of the file but still get FileNotFoundException. But if I copy the path and put `cat` in front of the path. it does print out the file content to the terminal

Comment: Are you sure the application has the right permission to read the file? You could try temporary to set 775 permission recursively to json folder.

Answer (score 0):

The maven structure for this is `src/main/webapp/` there will be a non-public `WEB-INF/` which is a good place for personalized json: `WEB-INF/JSON/` (case sensitive).

To get the physical root directory of the webapp one can use servlet context or jsf context. `ServletContext.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/JSON")`. Possibly deploy the war as "exploded."

Alternatively you could use an external configuration as allowed in Spring.

Default, template files, can be stored as resources, and copied to the file system.

```
URL url = getClass().getResource("/data/JSON/new.json");
Path path = Paths.get(url.toURI());
Path path2 = Paths.get(request.getServletContext().getRealPath("/WEB-INF/JSON/untitled.json"));
Files.copy(path, paths2);
```

Comment: My application is not .jsp based. So I can't even get this solution to run. Sadly